# Why all my ports are closed

Tags: iptables

I tried to scan my Ubuntu for open ports with NMAP. The result was only port 631 was open.
How is it possible ? I scanned for port 80 and it says it`s closed.

Comment: Do you expect something to listening on port 80?

Comment: If I`m using the browser and surfing the internet, port 80 should accept output rule ? I mean, if the port 80 closed, how i can surf in web pages ?

Comment: You have this totally wrong. A web server is listening on port 80 for incoming connections. I assume your system is not a server, so having port 80 closed is expected, as `nmap` scans for open *incoming* ports. Read up on networking fundamentals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Port 631 is the cups printing service, it is installed by default. Also by default, no other servers are installed, so nothing is listening on any port. This is what 'Closed' means.